# What is the package in Indigo supports webcam in laptop?

Tags: ros, opencv, webcam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Packages available for webcams are only for usb webcam and few for laptop cams but i cant find any Package for Indigo rather than Hydro, so what is the Indigo package supports laptop webcams

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210867/what-is-the-package-in-indigo-supports-webcam-in-laptop?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is not an UVC camera, you could try this one:
https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam

otherwise:

uvc_camera or (still maintained) libuvc_camera.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0